# How do I select an iframe using java selenium if it doesn't have name or id

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to select an `iframe` in selenium java but the element doesn't have a Name or Id attribute. How should I get it? (I want to use the `switchTo` to switch to it)

The website I am trying to get the `iframe` from is `jklm.fun` and the **xpath** of the `iframe` is

```
"/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/iframe"
```

(you need to be in a game for the `iframe` to exist)

Comment: It turned out there was no issue at all it was just the fact I ran it inside a while loop so it would switch to the iframe and then keep trying to find an iframe inside that iframe thus giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

Same way you select anything, based on their tree position: regular CSS selector. You query-select `body div div div iframe` and you're almost certainly going to get it (unless you have lots of three-deep divs with iframes in them, in which case what on earth is going on on that webpage =), but if that still gives you multiple options, narrow the query selector using tactical [:nth-child(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-classes.

Comment: How would i use this with the switchTo in selenium?

Comment: By applying standard logic? Get the list of all frames on the page, and the one frame you need, then `driver.switchTo().frame(allFrames.indexOf(myFrame))`

Comment: I'll try to do that

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to go with absolute xpath :

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/iframe
```

rather have a relative xpath.

Having said that, as far as switching is concerned, there are multiple ways:

1. Using `driver.switchTo()`

This basically provides 3 overloaded methods: -

with index :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame(index)
```

with name or ID:-

```
driver.switchTo().frame(nameOrId)
```

with web element

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement)
```

so out of these 3, we can easily use 2 of them since id or name isn't available in your case.

Using the index:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("here pass the index if you know. ")
```

Using frame web element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/iframe")))
```

this should work for you.

2. The other way we have is with Explicit waits:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/iframe")));
   ```

This is more convenient, way to switch to iframe in `angular` or `react based Application.`

Comment: I think there is only 1 iframe on the page, but passing index as 0 doesn't work for some reason. If I do driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe") it works but when I put that into the .frame() it also doesn't work.

Comment: Did your try index as 1 as well ? Also it's pretty much clear when you say by.tagName works,. Cause that will be the example of 3rd case which I have described above.

Comment: I tried index 1 as well and it didn't work. when I did driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe") it still didn't work
it gives me "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe"}"

Comment: Try explicit waits, should be enough to handle all these situation.

Comment: I am running the switchTo inside a while loop so it just constantly tries to switch

Comment: Read my answer carefully line by line. You will find explicit waits, also not sure what is infinite while loop here